# Javascript object from string

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I need to build an object string by string, and then use eval() to create the object.

I was successful doing this with an array of objects, but the next part, an object, is not working.

These three jsFiddles show the progression:

[Chart with normal array (pieData) and object (pieOptions)](http://jsfiddle.net/81fpdc44/)

[Chart with array formed of strings - works](http://jsfiddle.net/81fpdc44/2/)

[Add object formed of strings - no work](http://jsfiddle.net/81fpdc44/1/)

---

There is considerable discussion about why I use `eval()`. The array and object used for data and options respectively are both formed bit-by-bit as strings, and then glomped together into an array and an object. This jsFiddle will demonstrate a (simpler) version of my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/81fpdc44/3/

Please show me how to make s1...s5 into an array without using `eval()`. Am I missing something *(not an uncommon situation...)* ?

---

**For Posterity: The code**

Working (array):

```
<canvas id="pieChart" height="400" width="300"></canvas>

pieD  = '{value:25, color:"red"},';
pieD += '{value:5, color:"blue"},';
pieD += '{value:25, color:"palegreen"},';
pieD += '{value:10, color:"darkcyan"},';
pieD += '{value:35, color:"wheat"}';
eval('pieData = ['+pieD+']');

var pieOptions = {
    annotateDisplay : true,
    segmentShowStroke : false,
    segmentStrokeColor : "white",
    segmentStrokeWidth : 1,
    percentageInnerCutout : 0,
    animation: false,
    animationSteps : 100,
    animationEasing : "easeOutQuart",
    animateRotate : true,
    animateScale : false,
    legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
};


var ctx = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData,pieOptions);
```

Not working:

```
pieO  = 'annotateDisplay : true,';
pieO += 'segmentShowStroke : false,';
pieO += 'segmentStrokeColor : "white",';
pieO += 'segmentStrokeWidth : 1,';
pieO += 'percentageInnerCutout : 0,';
pieO += 'animation: false,';
pieO += 'animationSteps : 100,';
pieO += 'animationEasing : "easeOutQuart",';
pieO += 'animateRotate : true,';
pieO += 'animateScale : false,';
pieO += 'legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"';
eval('pieOptions = {'+pieO+'}');
```

Comment: Why would you  use eval? Just build the object!

Comment: Why do you think you have to do this using eval?

Comment: If there is another way, I'll take it.  However, I have not been successful joining the strings into an object.  To make matters more difficult, all javascript is itself ajaxed onto the page as a string.  *I sometimes think I should have chosen an easier career, like pediatric brain surgery or inventing nth dimensional quantum mechanics.*

Comment: `var obj = { key: value,...key: value(nth)}` do not `eval()`

Comment: If the response is a string, that string probably is JSON, JSON is a string representation of a structure, in that case you should use the `JSON.parse` method for parsing the string. What you are trying to do is _madness_. It's very  fragile, error-prone and an anti-pattern.

Comment: Why are they strings and not objects to start? Makes no sense... Remove the quotes and magically they are objects. Push them into an array and you have an array of objects. Now for the other one, why is it strings to start? Why don't you just set it to an object?

Comment: @crashwap _"how to create the array and object without using eval"_ See post

Comment: When you're including external resources in jsfiddle, using the github link directly is a bad idea. Github serves its raw files with mime type text/plain. Some web browsers, quite reasonably, refuse to interpret this as a javascript file because it is not application/javascript. Try using https://rawgit.com/ to reference these instead.

Comment: @moreON - Thanks. I'll do that in future. And thank you so much for explaining the reason *why*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `eval` for creating an array of objects:

```
s1 = '{value:25, color:"red"}';
s2 = '{value:5, color:"blue"}';
s3 = '{value:25, color:"palegreen"}';
s4 = '{value:10, color:"darkcyan"}';
s5 = '{value:35, color:"wheat"}';
var pieData = [ s1+s2+s3+s4+s5 ];
```

The above code snippet is a wrong way of doing this. Here you shouldn't create a string representation of an object (those are not valid JSON strings) when you need a real object. What you should do is:

```
var s1 = {value:25, color:"red"};
var s2 = {value:5, color:"blue"};
var s3 = {value:25, color:"palegreen"};
var s4 = {value:10, color:"darkcyan"};
var s5 = {value:35, color:"wheat"};
var pieData = [ s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 ];
```

Now `pieData` is an array of objects. Done!

Comment: Thanks m8. You guys have really made me think. Why is it that it's the rappers and dancers who wear headbands when its us coders who sometimes feel the need to wrap something around our heads because they're about to explode with the concepts with which we grapple? *On the other hand, it might just be that I'm not that smart. I am open to that possibility... and on a night like tonight it feels more like a probability...* Thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this. The key was understanding that `eval()` must not ever be used, under any circumstances. *(At my present skill level, at least)*

Aside from the ajax injection, and JavaScript code being injected with it, here's what I was trying to do. I had these values in variables:

```
cu = 3;
py = 5;
fs = 7;
qz = 9;
ch = 11;
am = 13;
mi = 15;
mo = 17;
```

I had to create an array that was part text/part variable (I thought...). So, I tried this:

```
pDat = ['{value:'+cu+'}, {value:'+py+'}, {value:'+fs+'}, {value:'+qz+'}, {value:'+ch+'}, {value:'+am+'}, {value:'+mi+'}, {value:'+mo+'}'];
```

That didn't work. So I tried:

```
eval('pDat = [{value:'+cu+'}, {value:'+py+'}, {value:'+fs+'}, {value:'+qz+'}, {value:'+ch+'}, {value:'+am+'}, {value:'+mi+'}, {value:'+mo+'}']');
```

That worked for the array, but not for the object.

With the good advice from Vohuman, guest271314, epascarello and other good souls, I went back to the drawing board and refactored the code so that I could just do this:

(And it worked for everything - I was even able to add the variables with the color codes):

```
pDat = [{value:cu, color:CuCol}, {value:py, color:PyCol}, {value:fs, color:FsCol}, {value:qz, color:QzCol}, {value:ch, color:ChCol}, {value:am, color:AmCol}, {value:mi, color:MiCol}, {value:mo, color:MOCol}];

oOpt = {
    annotateDisplay : true,
    segmentShowStroke : false,
    segmentStrokeColor : "white",
    segmentStrokeWidth : 1,
    percentageInnerCutout : 0,
    animation: false,
    animationSteps : 100,
    animationEasing : "easeOutQuart",
    animateRotate : true,
    animateScale : false,
    legendTemplate : '<ul class="<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style="background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>'
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");
updateChart(ctx,pDat,pOpt,true,false);
```

Note:

FWIW, `CuCol`, `PyCol` etc are just vars that look like this:

```
CuCol = '#ffe382';
PyCol = '#1bb3a5';
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, adjusted double quotes at `<ul>` string attributes to single quotes .

Try using `String.prototype.split()` , `Array.prototype.map()` , `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/(^[a-zA-Z]+)(?=\s|:)/g` to match characters a-z case insensitive followed by space character or colon character `":"` property of object string ; `JSON.stringify()` , `JSON.parse()`

```js
pieO  = 'annotateDisplay : true,';
pieO += 'segmentShowStroke : false,';
pieO += 'segmentStrokeColor : "white",';
pieO += 'segmentStrokeWidth : 1,';
pieO += 'percentageInnerCutout : 0,';
pieO += 'animation: false,';
pieO += 'animationSteps : 100,';
pieO += 'animationEasing : "easeOutQuart",';
pieO += 'animateRotate : true,';
pieO += 'animateScale : false,';
pieO += 'legendTemplate : "<ul class=\'<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\'><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\'background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\'></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"'

pieO = pieO.split(",").map(function(val, index) {
    val = val.replace(/(^[a-zA-Z]+)(?=\s|:)/g, function(match) {
      return JSON.stringify(match)
    });
    return JSON.parse("{" + val + "}")
});

console.log(pieO)
```

Comment: I know it's fun to do uncommon stuff, but this is really unnecessary.  It actually doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Vohuman Requirement appear to include _"I must build array and object from textual strings."_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012081/javascript-object-from-string/34012449#comment55780301_34012081 . Not certain how to evaluate whether a process "makes sense" or not ? Many errors , mistakes and also blunders have led to novel developments , or even enlightenment ?

Comment: That's creative. I said it doesn't make sense as it made the process unnecessarily complicated. I hope it helps him/her.

Comment: Gents, both your suggestions helped immensely (and he's a him). I was suffering from a combined lack of experience, training and examples. Your suggestions / examples helped me to solve the problem. When I achieve sufficient zen humility to post what worked, with you will likely need belts to keep your sides from splitting. *(from laughing...)*